# CSS: container to show PRE tag with scroll bars

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, pre

I have some server-side code that outputs stuff in html `<pre></pre>` tags and I would like to be able to put them in a container with scroll bars. (Specifically, table cells - with equal widths). Obviously I want to preserve the `<pre>` tag whitespace formatting.

([see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78s87/4/)):

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td><pre>
function thisIsATest(bla){
    Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789
}
        </pre></td>
        <td><pre>
function thisIsATest(bla){
    Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789
}
        </pre></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table { 
    width: 100%; 
    border: 1px solid red;
}
td { 
    width: 50%;
    overflow: scroll; 
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[image]

(I am testing it in Firefox). What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: What did you wanted to achieve? Whats wrong with your fiddle?

Comment: The table does not fit the window, I want it to be completely visible, reducing the column widths. In the full page's code, the table is in a fixed-width div, and the right portion of the table that extends past the width of the div is hidden. Is this not apparent in your view of the JSFiddle? I have now also tested it in IE11 and I'm getting the same result as in Firefox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

The easiest way to fix this is to add: `table-layout:fixed;` (ironic) to the CSS for `table`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/78s87/11/)

---

Original Answer:

Using `pre` tags within `table` elements is notoriously problematic, namely due to issues with relative width calculations which throw scrolling and actual width setting right out. As such, I'd avoid a table based setup, not least of which because you're also not displaying tabulated data (aaah semantics!).

I'd change your layout per the below:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78s87/8/)

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='col'> <pre>
function thisIsATest(bla){
    Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789
}
        </pre>

    </div>
    <div class='col'> <pre>
function thisIsATest(bla){
    Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789
}
        </pre>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.col {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

---

### Update

To fake a multi-line (row) table layout, use `div` element with `dislpay` set as appropriate:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78s87/9/)

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'> <pre>
function thisIsATest(bla){
    Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789
}
        </pre>

        </div>
        <div class='cell'> <pre>
function thisIsATest(bla){
    Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789
}
        </pre>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'> <pre>
function thisIsATest(bla){
    Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789
}
        </pre>

        </div>
        <div class='cell'> <pre>
function thisIsATest(bla){
    Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789 Testing 123456789
}
        </pre>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.table {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
.cell {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    display:table-cell;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiosity, how could I then achieve the equivalent of multiple rows (cells' tops and bottoms aligned)? Edit: Ah I'm being stupid. I just have another container div for each row

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/78s87/9/ you can 'fake' a table layout using `display`

Comment: @Jodes - something about this had been annoying me, please see the top of my answer for a revision which may save you having to restructure your HTML. That said, semantically I'd tend to avoid using `table`, but you can make it work.